# How to detect the very first run in an ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've search a lot of that and as conclusion:

- advertisement id
- vendor id
- keychain

But as far as I know, all these ids can be change by users, and keychain can be disabled in icloud setting. Some says use `NSUserDefault` but this will be removed once remove the app.

What I want to achieve is detect first run on a specific device even uninstall and reinstall.

I am new to ios dev, can some one help? thanks in advance.

Comment: basically these way is enough to detect, most user wont bother reset the advertisement id or keychain, and keychain is in the device, icloud is just backup, so you can use either or both to detect

Comment: Hi Tj3n, do you mean that even a user disable the keychain, my setting will be saved in device locally even the user uninstall and reinstall my app? thanks

Comment: Yes, they seems only might gone if the user restore the device, which mostly wont happen, resetting the advertising also 99% user wont do anyway

Comment: Thanks, just thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the **Vendor-ID** and storing it to **Keychain** is the best way you can achieve your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay. Do you mean that the info I save to KeyChain won't be changed or removed when user uninstalls and reinstall my app? I'll try this and thanks. If your reply this again will be even better.

Comment: Yes, when you install the app for the first time, check if there is already a vendor id for the app in keychain. if you find one, use it as your device id else get a new Vendor-ID and save it to keychain. you can use SSKeyChain https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain.  a simple wrapper around keychain that makes your task easy. :)

Comment: There is no need to use vendor-id. Just generate your own UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading a key out of `UserDefaults` that you know won't exist.

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "YourAppNamePrefixHasRunBefore") {
  // do whatever you need to do
  UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "YourAppNamePrefixHasRunBefore") // set the key so on the next run this test fails 
}
```

You may need to validate syntax, but it should be pretty close.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but, the userdefaults key/value pair won't be removed after user uninstall my app?

Comment: Yes, it will be removed. That store is specific to your app. I misunderstood the question if you want the data to persist after an uninstall.